# Where does the Binding of Isaac store its saved data?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac

I know you can't save your game in the Binding of Isaac, I am referring to the local save data: unlocks, collection, stats, etc.

I move between three computers regularly (home pc, laptop, and work computer) and it's a pain in the ass not having all of the characters unlocked and whatnot.

This game is supposed to use Steam cloud (at least I thought).. I have it enabled in the game's properties, but the save data only exists on my laptop.

So yeah, anybody know where those files are at so I can copy them over to my other computers?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The game's save data is contained in two files, both of which need to be moved between computers in order to get everything migrated properly.

These files are **so.sol** and **serial.txt**. I have a Mac and a Windows machine, so I'll go ahead and list the location of said files on both platforms (if anyone has any Linux info, feel free to chip in).

**On the PC:**

serial.txt: Can be found in the game's steam installation folder, something along the lines of

```
C:\Program Files\Steam\SteamApps\common\the binding of isaac\
```

so.sol: Can be found over at

```
%appdata%\Macromedia\Flash Player\#SharedObjects\<some random string>\localhost\
```

The "random string" bit is some combination of letters and numbers which is impossible to predict. Assuming you've ever run the game, simply search for "so.sol" at "%appdata%\Macromedia\Flash Player#SharedObjects" (you can type this in your run prompt to get there). On my machine I have several so.sol files, but only one is on a path that looks exactly like the one I specified, and that's the one that counts.

**On the Mac:**

serial.txt: Can be found in the game's steam installation folder, something along the lines of

```
~/Library/Application Support/Steam/SteamApps/common/the binding of isaac/
```

so.sol: Much like the PC, only over at

```
~/Library/Preferences/Macromedia/Flash Player/#SharedObjects/<some random string>/localhost/
```

---

As a final note, I will stress again that you need to move both files, and that you need to launch the game at least once on the target machine to know where they should go.

The Binding of Issac cannot support steam cloud as it is a flash game and is not allowed to access the local filesystem except for using per site storage (or local shared objects, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_shared_object). It is impossible for the game to use steam cloud while it is running in the flash player (as opposed to AIR or some other language).

Comment: In addition to answer:
I use dropbox for synchronizing this (serial.txt and so.sol) files.

Comment: This answer should be updated, since now BoI uses the Steam cloud.

Comment: @Kappei That would prove super fantastic, but I just moved so my second computer is not very operational and I can't corroborate this. Is there some sort of official statement about this feature? I did not manage to find anything, and keeping this feature hidden strikes me as insane...

Comment: Sorry, no official announcement can be found... It just suddenly started working. It now synchs the game files while starting and when closing the game, and yes, it's a little insane not announcing it.

Comment: @Kappei I'll give this a more in-depth look once I manage to find some time, seeing how the files may still be stored in the same locations as stated above, as well as in the cloud. Of course, if you care to shed some light on the matter you are more than welcome to edit the answer.

Comment: steam cloud support for BOI is limited to serial.txt (ie. your  achievements and statistics).  it doesn't include unlocked challenges, etc.  (source: steam's logs/cloud_log.txt)

Answer (score 8):

Just chiming in that for the Linux version, so.sol lives in:

```
~/.macromedia/Flash_Player/#SharedObjects/<random string>/localhost/so.sol
```

I do not appear to have a serial.txt file. I'm using the Humble Bundle version, not the Steam one, which is probably related.

Comment: I can't verify this now, but since all data (youtube etc.) seem to be under that random string, it looks like the file is shared by all games on localhost.  If it's true, it should be pointed out since deleting the file (e.g. to reset death stats) would mean deleting all data from all Flash games!

Answer (score 1):

FIY, I'm using Windows 7 and for me, the file was in:

`C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Macromedia\Flash Player\#SharedObjects\FEP7BL8G\localhost`

(Replace username with your own username.)

Comment: That actually lines up with my answer, seeing how %appdata% contains the path "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming".

Answer (score -2):

In OS 10 I found this.
C:\Program Files(x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\The Binding of Iassac Rebirth
In side it was a text file called savedatapath click on it and it produced,
Save Data Path: C:\Users\User/Documents/My Games/Binding of Isaac Afterbirth/.
The second user being my user ID but with this data you shoud be able to find your saved files.

Comment: This answer adds nothing not covered in more detail by the accepted answer.