# How do I unlock the Cathedral in the Wrath of the Lamb DLC?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac, wrath-of-the-lamb

I bought the Wrath of the Lamb DLC, but the Cathedral isn't unlocked yet. How is this unlocked?  Is it because I haven't beaten the Sheol with all the characters yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to beat Sheol with all of the characters to unlock the Cathedral, it's available from the beginning.

Three situations are possible here:

- the DLC didn't install correctly. Can you see the new enemies, bosses and basement maps? You should have already encountered at least some spiders. If you didn't, there's been a problem downloading the DLC, and you'll have to reinstall the game. [Backup your savegames](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/34600/23609) to be sure you don't lose anything, remove your local data and redownload them. This should do the trick.
- you beat It Lives and a Demon room appeared. [As I've experienced](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/71785/23609), if you get a Demon Room after beating It Lives, only the trapdoor to Sheol will appear in the main room. The entrance to the Cathedral will be in the Demon Room/Chapel.
- you didn't notice the entrance. The first time I almost missed it. If you beat It Lives without a Demon room spawning, you'll get a trapdoor to Sheol and a beam of light that will bring you to the Cathedral. If you headed straight to the trapdoor, you may have not noticed the beam of light coming from the Heavens.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the dlc is installed pretty correctly, I can see the new enemies, rooms, trinkets and all that stuff

Actually i didn't even had it lives as a boss when i posted this question (I had mom's heart) but now I have him now so let me try again.

I know what the entrance looks like. I'll try again now to look for it (now that I have it lives)

Comment: @DemircanCelebi I assumed you had It Lives because you can't get to Sheol if you don't unlock it(unless you get the Demon room or through the shovel item)

Comment: I got my binding of isaac after the halloween update and I had got Sheol unlocked after i beat Mom. Now that I've unlocked all 11 endings, I can go to cathedral too, thanks for the help :)